# Order of product of non-disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $a$ and $b$ be two non-disjoint cycles of order $m$ and $n$. Is there any general formula for the order of $a b$? I understand that we can convert any non-disjoint cycles into disjoint cycles and compute the order as the lcm of the orders of individual cycles. I am looking for a formula which takes information about $a$ and $b$ as input.

Comment: There is a theorem that says that given any $m,n,r$, all exceeding 1, you can find permutations $a,b$ such that the order of $a$ is $m$, the order of $b$ is $n$, and the order of $ab$ is $r$. I think that's even true for cycles, but I encourage you to do some experiments to see how wild the triples $m,n,r$ are that you can come up with.

Comment: No there is no such formula. There are many possible values for the order of $ab$. For example, the order of the product of two non-disjoint $4$-cycles can be $1,2,3,4,5,6$ or $7$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If they are both cycles, then the order of $ab$ cannot be greater than the largest order of an element of $S_{m+n-1}$.

Comment: @Derek, of course, I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

As has been noted in the comments, there is no such formula. The order of $ab$ depends on the common elements and their positions in the two cycles.